# Pulling metafields for variants in Shopify

Tags: shopify, product, liquid, variant

I am trying to pull metafields for variants and/or single products.

Effectively i have a catalog of products, some are simple products some have variants. For instance, some products are beds with variants of different sizes. therefore the metafield dimensions are different for these products.

I am unaware if there is a liquid command to pull full array of metafields of a product.

What i am looking to implement is.

Define if product has variants.
if yes -> Pull array/list of  variant metafields for selected variant.
if no -> pull list of array/list of product metafields.

i am capable of showing product metafield values or variant values such as below, however this does not feel efficient and i am unable to determine if the product is a variant or single product.

```
                {%- if product.metafields.global.length_cm.value != blank -%}
                <tr>
                    <td>Seat Width (cm)</td>
                    <td>{{ product.metafields.global.seat_width_cm.value }}</td>
                </tr>
                {%- endif -%}
                {%- if product.metafields.global.width_cm.value != blank -%}
                <tr>
                    <td>Seat Depth (cm)</td>
                    <td>{{ product.metafields.global.seat_depth_cm.value }}</td>
                </tr>
                {%- endif -%}
```

---

is there a way also to inject code into a liquid command.

such as something along the lines of this?

```
{% assign main_dimensions = "width_cm, height_cm, depth_cm, length_cm" | split: ','%}
{% assign main_dimensions_title = "Width (cm), Height (cm), Depth (cm), Length(cm)" | split: ','%}

{{ main_dimensions_title[1]}} - {{ product.metafields.global.main_dimensions[1].value }}
```

Comment: check like this `{% if product.variants.size %}` to determine if products has variants or not

Comment: Amazing, that works. So if i set {% if product.variants.size !=0 %} then it is a variant. Perfect!

Comment: is there a way to pull values from something along the lines of {{product.metafields.global}}

Comment: along with line means to say into cart page?

Comment: Hi Onkar, thank you for your assistance, i have made an edit at the bottom, is this possible?

Comment: yes, for all member simple use the forloop to iterate the items.

Comment: Hi Onkar, unfortunately it does not pull the value which using the array to parse the text to the liquid command.